# undefined local variable or method `api_v1_airlines' for #<AirlinesControllerTest:0x000000565ff5a928>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I am not sure why minitest is not recognising my route:

```
# airlines_controller_test.rb
class AirlinesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    test "should get index" do
      get api_v1_airlines
      assert_response :success
    end
  end

` api_v1_airlines GET    /api/v1/airlines(.:format)                                                                        api/v1/airlines#index {:params=>:slug}
```

`

I ran the test and it gave me

```
`Error:
AirlinesControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `api_v1_airlines' for #<AirlinesControllerTest:0x0000006532df84b8>
    test/controllers/airlines_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:AirlinesControllerTest>'`
```

what am I doing wrong? It is not recognizing the route but it is defined in rails routes. What am I not including in my test file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers), you should use the `*_url` form of the route helper.

```rb
class AirlinesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    test "should get index" do
      get api_v1_airlines_url
      assert_response :success
    end
  end
```